# How can I control NHibernate's datetime formatting?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, datetime

I'm having problems with NHibernate, where the statements running on the server are failing when it tries to use a `DateTime` parameter.

The parameter is being passed as `'2012-04-15 19:52:55.7230000'`, but this has too much precision to be converted into a `datetime`:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
    INSERT INTO [People].[NameChanges]
     (
        Revision, 
        MadeAtDateTime,
        MadeAtOffset,
        MadeBy,
        Title,
        Forename,
        Surname,
        Person,
        ID
    ) 
    VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8)',
    N'@p0 int,
      @p1 datetime,
      @p2 bigint,
      @p3 nvarchar(4000),
      @p4 nvarchar(4000),
      @p5 nvarchar(4000),
      @p6 nvarchar(4000),
      @p7 bigint,
      @p8 uniqueidentifier',

     @p0=0,
     @p1='2012-04-15 19:52:55.7230000',
     @p2=36000000000,
     @p3=N'',
     @p4=N'Mr',
     @p5=N'Ezra',
     @p6=N'Awesomesauce',
     @p7=1969929945,
     @p8='4D045A70-A474-4D36-8841-DDB16BBB147D'
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 0
>
> Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

To confirm the problem, I ran the following statement:

```
declare @DateTime datetime = '2012-04-15 19:52:55.7230000'
```

And recieved the message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm running on a SQL 2008 Express database, but I need the schema to be compatible with SQL 2005, so this precludes the option to switch to the `datetime2` datatype as an easy workaround.

It feels the formatting is more part of the SQL ADO.NET driver than NHibernate, but I don't know enough about how NHibernate generates statements to be more precise in asking where I need to go to change the formatting to something the database can parse.

Ideally, I'd like to use ISO 8601 or continue to use ANSI SQL formatting to avoid any culture-related problems.

What can I do to correct this problem?

Comment: Can you sow us some code and error messages you get?

Comment: How does *your* nh query look like?

Comment: I'm using datetime in all my database an never had an issue with that. How did you map this?

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger: There is no query here, Stefan. This insert is the result of adding an object to the `ISession` and flushing. I've used `datetime` extensively in previous projects without incident. I'm not sure what's happening here either.

Comment: Digging, the values are being mapped as part of an `ICompositeUserType` implementation. It looks like NHibernate "guessed" the type of the field as a `DbTimestamp`, and subsequently has the wrong precision when translating to T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate's formatting of `DateTime` values is controlled by its internal type system, through the `IType` interface.

In my scenario, NHibernate decided that the serializable type for `DateTime` was `DbTimestamp`. This type includes a greater degree of precision than is natively available in SQL Server's `datetime` data-type, so causing an overflow to occur when trying to convert the string into a `datetime`.

The solution was to explicitly set the custom type to use NHibernate's `Type.DateTime` type, which only includes time to the second and is an appropriate fit for the `datetime` type.